# how to avoid data overwrite (lost) write - update on same object by multiple thread in Cassandra

Tags: multithreading, transactions, cassandra, timestamp, locking

I'am running a multiple thread to do modification and update on the same object!

let's keep it simple:

I have an  obj1: | id | counter | timestamp | :)

run() 3 Thread t1, t2 t3 to do counter++

I'am new in Cassandra so from your experience, how can I lock the object to do my update or witch solution you suggest for me to use to avoid the data overwrite in such situation!

looking to hear from you and thank you

Comment: Can you post the **CREATE TABLE** script of your table ?

Comment: it's a sample table with a simple replication strategy factor 1

Answer (score 0):

There are no locks. Instead of mutating same object, write a log of mutations to reconcile. Look up CRDT or event sourcing and depending on scenario things can be implemented a little differently.

Alternatively you can use light weight transactions and keep retrying until your mutation works, but your throughput will be very poor in comparison. Depending on your concurrency/throughput requirements it may be sufficient though

```
UPDATE purchases SET balance=-200 WHERE user='user1' IF balance=-208;
```

If it fails retry with new IF/balance clause.

Worth mentioning there is a counter type:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_counter_t.html
if your just incrementing or decrementing which would do your specific case.

Comment: Thanks Chris, but i didn't get your first part regarding a log of mutations to reconcile. also I tried the light weight transactions but doesn't work for me, the counter is just a use case, it's not of type counter, If there's a solution when I get the Object form DB + do my operation and during the Update i will check the timestamp in real time if it's changed or not and based on that I commit ?

Comment: "doesnt work for me"?  but yeah, a timestamp **uuid** would work to check if modified from your last read (can be collisions on same ms if just use timestamp). It would be very slow though. [CRDT](https://hal.inria.fr/file/index/docid/445975/filename/icdcs09-treedoc.pdf) and [event sourcing](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) is how you still have very fast writes while avoiding concurrency conflicts. Also called things like OT, CQRS, kinda a rabbit hole but they have similar goal - avoid conflicts. Id recommend spending some time googling/youtube

Comment: thanks for the links i will check them and come back to you if i find some solution for this essay! any comment suggestion from your part are welcome